# my data is not updating on online server .the data is updating on local

Tags: xpath-1.0

```
<?php include('../include/config.php');
if(empty($_SESSION['sus']) && empty($_SESSION['spa']))
{
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
/*##########################################*/
$id=$_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST['save']))
                                                    {

                                            define ("MAX_SIZE","1000"); 
                                            function getExtension($str)
                                            {
                                                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                                                 if (!$i) { return ""; }
                                                 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
                                                 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
                                                 return $ext;
                                            }

                                            $errors=0;
                                            $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
                                            if ($image) 
                                            {
                                                $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                                                $extension = getExtension($filename);
                                                $extension = strtolower($extension);
                                                if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") 
                                                    && ($extension != "gif")&& ($extension != "JPG") && ($extension != "JPEG") 
                                                    && ($extension != "PNG") && ($extension != "GIF")) 
                                                {
                                                    echo '<h3>Unknown extension!</h3>';
                                                    $errors=1;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

                                                    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
                                                    {
                                                        echo '<h4>You have exceeded the size limit!</h4>';
                                                        $errors=1;
                                                    }

                                                    $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
                                                    $newname="img/".$image_name;


                                                    $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
                                                    if (!$copied) 
                                                    {
                                                        echo '<h3>Copy unsuccessfull!</h3>';
                                                        $errors=1;
                                                    }
                                                    else //echo '<h3>uploaded successfull!</h3>';


                                $title=$_POST['title'];

                                $content=$_POST['content'];
                                $sql="update home set title='$title',content='$content',img='$newname' where id='$id'";
                                        $res=mysql_query($sql);
                                            if($res)
                                            {
                                                echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Uploaded')</script>";
                                     echo "<script>window.location='admin_home.php'</script>";
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        echo "failed submit";
                                       echo "<script>window.location='admin_home.php'</script>";
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }

}
?>
```

actully i updating code on local host it is updating but in online server it is not updating how to update the code

actully i updating code on local host it is updating but in online server it is not updating how to update the code 
actully i updating code on local host it is updating but in online server it is not updating how to update the code

Answer (score 1):

What error code do you get?

```
echo $_FILES['image']['error']

0 => 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success'
1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini'
2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form'
3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded'
4 => 'No file was uploaded'
6 => 'Missing a temporary folder'
7 => 'Failed to write file to disk.'
8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.'
```